# xdescribe vs fdescribe in jasmine

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, jasmine, karma-runner

- `fdescribe` -  Execute if the spec.ts file is defined with `fdescribed`
- `xdescribe` - Never execute if spec.ts file is defined with  `xdescribed`

Is my understand is correct? and what about if am defined both `xdescribe` and `fdescribe` in two separate `spec.ts` file?

Comment: `xdescribe` will eXclude those specs from execution. `fdescribe` will execute those specs. if you have both the `fdescribe` specs will be executed and reset is ignored

Comment: So if am use `fdescribe` then we don't need to use `xdescribe`? correct?

Comment: yes, if you are intent is to include only those specs then `xdescribe` is not required

Answer (score 41):

- `fdescribe` - **focused** describe. If it exists, jasmine *will run only* `fdescribe` spec and ignore other type of describe (`describe` and `xdescribe`).
- `xdescribe` - **disabled** describe. It *will never* be executed.

Some scenarios to gain more understanding:

Scenario 1 - `describe` only

```js
describe('test1', ..)

describe('test2', ..)

describe('test3', ..)

// Specs executed:
// test1
// test2
// test3
```

Scenario 2 - single `fdescribe`

```js
fdescribe('test1', ..)

describe('test2', ..)

describe('test3', ..)

// Specs executed:
// test1
```

Scenario 3 - multiple `fdescribe`

```js
fdescribe('test1', ..)

fdescribe('test2', ..)

describe('test3', ..)

// Specs executed:
// test1
// test2
```

Scenario 4 - single `xdescribe`

```js
xdescribe('test1', ..)

describe('test2', ..)

describe('test3', ..)

// Specs executed:
// test2
// test3
```

Scenario 4 - multiple `xdescribe`

```js
xdescribe('test1', ..)

xdescribe('test2', ..)

describe('test3', ..)

// Specs executed:
// test3
```

Scenario 5 - `fdescribe` and `xdescribe` exists

```js
fdescribe('test1', ..)

xdescribe('test2', ..)

describe('test3', ..)

// Specs executed:
// test1
```

Beside those two, Jasmine also has `fit` and `xit` with same rules.

Interestingly, Jasmine 3 will show an error when running the test if `fdescribe` spec exists to prevent users from inadvertently disabled other specs.

The error message:

```
Incomplete: fit() or fdescribe() was found
```

Reference:

- https://jasmine.github.io/api/3.5/global.html#fdescribe
- https://jasmine.github.io/api/3.5/global.html#xdescribe

Comment: What about `ddescribe`? :)

Answer (score 18):

- `xdescribe` will **eXclude** those specs from execution.
- `fdescribe` will **first execute** those specs. If you have both, the fdescribe specs will be executed, while 'describe' and 'xdescribe' are ignored.