# Angular 9: inclue all test case in code coverage

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, code-coverage

Firstly, I tried all the questions & answers related to this topic. Additionally and I tried related questions and try to solve it but no success. So please read my question thoroughly.

**i refer link** : [**Ng test**](https://www.w3resource.com/angular/ng-test.php)

**i using command** : `ng test --code-coverage=true`

I have written a **`2000`** test case but run only **`150`** test case because

150 test case (write **`fdescribe`**)

100 test case (**`xdescribe`**)
.so I run the above command then only **`150`** test case reports generated.

**But I want to all (2000) test case report** including (**`xdescribe,fdescribe`**) test case

Comment: There is a good explanation of this in the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48740288/xdescribe-vs-fdescribe-in-jasmine

Comment: hi @OwenKelvin i refer link but i know thi case . but i want f and without x test case.

Answer (score 0):

### fdescribe and fit()

> Use it instead of describe() or it() during the implementation of small parts of your application. Only those test suites or single tests marked with these keywords will be run. This speeds up testing a lot.

### xdescribe() and xit() [(link to source)](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/jasmine-unit-testing-tutorial-4e757c2cbf42/)

> You can temporarily disable a suite using the xdescribe() function. It has the same signature (parameters) as a describe() function which means you can quickly disable your existing suites by simply adding an x to the function.
> **Specs within an xdescribe() function will be marked pending and not executed in the report.**

From the above two extracts, in your question you are running 2000 tests with 150 having fdescribe. Only the fdescribe test suites will be included in the report. For the xdescribe tests suites, by definition of the of when to use xdescribe, this tests will be excluded from the report. To run them you may have to change these tests to fdescribe